# Data duplicated(doubled) in Dataset.next_batch() method

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow

Assume that I have given only one test image.

I extract `images,labels` using `mnist.test.next_batch(100)`.

- When i give 1 test image, I am getting 2 images (same image duplicated)
- When I give 2 test images, I am getting 4 (2 images duplicated).

Same problem exists for training images.

I consoled the length of test images and train images inside read_data_sets method(...tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py).
It is giving correct length.

Here is my code.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True, validation_size=0)

images, labels = mnist.test.next_batch(100)
print len(images)  #double the actual length
```

Comment: What version of tensorflow is this? I'm getting `len(images) == 2`, as expected.

Comment: Returns 100 for me, what does it return for you?

Comment: Create a new MNIST data using [this](https://github.com/gskielian/JPG-PNG-to-MNIST-NN-Format).
Give only one image inside 'test-images/0' remove 'test-images/1'
convert to mnist format.
Replace contents of 'MNIST_data' with generated data.
Run the code.
I am getting 2(expected length is 1).

Comment: Why do you need to create data? Tensorflow downloads it automatically for you. I guess the problem is that you have both the ones you created and the ones tensorflow downloads, creating a duplicate.

Comment: I want to modify the program to detect a special symbol. 
I have replaced contents of MNIST_data with my generated files.
Tensorflow won't download data if data already exists.